# What encoding are Ruby Strings in?

Tags: ruby, string, encoding

Is it true that Ruby Strings are just a sequence of Unicode characters? If so, what specific encoding e.g. is it UTF-8, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Ruby strings are indeed UTF-8, as can be verified by [the `String#encoding` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-encoding):

```
llama@llama:~$ irb
irb(main):001:0> 'foo'.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

You can get a list of available encodings [via `Encoding::list`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Encoding.html#method-c-list):

```
irb(main):002:0> Encoding.list
=> [#<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>, #<Encoding:UTF-8>, #<Encoding:US-ASCII>, (etc...)]
```

And change the encoding of a string [with `String#force_encoding`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-force_encoding):

```
irb(main):003:0> 'foo'.force_encoding(Encoding::US_ASCII).encoding
=> #<Encoding:US-ASCII>
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. Starting from ruby 2.0 the default encoding for a string is `UTF-8` if is not explicitly stated in the source file, a command line switch or at time of creation. In ruby 1.9 however, the default encoding for a string will be `US-ASCII`. Because Ruby 1.9 is used in many production environments today, it should be taken into account. *Programming Ruby 1.9, The pragmatic programmer's Guide, Chapter 6, Strings*

Comment: @yeyo I just checked my `irb1.9.1` on Ubuntu, and the default there is also UTF-8. The default seems to be UTF-8 from 1.9.1 onwards, and US-ASCII for anything before.

Comment: @Doorknob冰 in your case the encoding is determined by `irb` from your current locale. Please note that I said `source file` and not `irb session`, whenever possible, feel free to consult the reference I provided. Also check Yu Hao's answer.

Answer (score 5):

The default encoding of a `String` is the same as the source file.

The default encoding of the source file is UTF-8 in Ruby 2.0 or later, or US-ASCII in Ruby 1.9 or earlier. You can specify the encoding by adding

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

in the beginning of a source file.

Comment: I would like to ask which source file: Ruby's source file or the source file of the program written in Ruby?

Comment: @b16db0 The source file you write.